# Can anyone help me this? HTTPS in Alibaba Cloud WA

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I have been told to notice this rule as follow:

"Before using the HTTPS protection feature in Alibaba Cloud WAF, you
must upload the server certificate and private key beforehand."

Does anyone know where I can find this? At Alibaba website or someplace?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "Procedure" on the following link, it describes how to authenticate and configure HTTPS certificates:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/27118.htm